# Execute a Typescript function according to a scenario in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, store, angular-lifecycle-hooks

In my application, I have two comboboxes in a component.
Their default values ​​are both `null`.

[image]

When selecting a period or a user, the value is sent to the store.
This allows you to use the period and the selected user in different components.

**Combobox.component TO Store:**

```
  onSelectedWalletsPeriod(period: Period) {
    this.store.setSelectedWalletsPeriod(period);
  }

  onSelectedWalletsUser(user: User) {
    this.store.setSelectedWalletsUser(user);
  }
```

**Store:**

```
export class MystoreComponentStore {

    private selectedWalletsPeriodSubject = new BehaviorSubject<Period>(null);
    private selectedWalletsUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(null);

    public selectedWalletsPeriod$ = this.selectedWalletsPeriodSubject.asObservable();
    public selectedWalletsUser$ = this.selectedWalletsUserSubject.asObservable();

    constructor() {}

    setSelectedWalletsPeriod(period: Period) {
        this.selectedWalletsPeriodSubject.next(period);
        this.selectedWalletSubject.next(null);

        /# DEBUG #/
        console.log('selectedPeriod:', period);
    }

    setSelectedWalletsUser(user: User) {
        this.selectedWalletsUserSubject.next(user);
        this.selectedWalletSubject.next(null);

        /# DEBUG #/
        console.log('selectedUser:', user);
    }
}
```

**Store TO Result.component:**

```
export class ResultComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  selectedWalletsPeriod: Period = null;
  selectedWalletsUser: User = null;

  constructor(public store: MystoreComponentStore) { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.store.selectedWalletsPeriod$.subscribe(period=> this.selectedWalletsPeriod = period);

    this.store.selectedWalletsUser$.subscribe(user=> this.selectedWalletsUser = user);
  }
}
```

To display the list of the second component, I have to select a period AND a user.
Until then everything works perfectly.

But what I would like to do is execute a function when a user AND a period are selected.
This function would also execute when changing the value of one of the two comboboxes.

This function will allow me to retrieve a wallet list from my database based on the period and the user.

I do not know how to do it. If you have an idea, I'm interested.

Here is a small example: [Stackblitz HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/execute-typescript-function-according-to-a-scenario-in-angular)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `combineLatest` to listen for the latest value of either select and then filter those value where not both values are set:

```js
combineLatest(this.store.selectedWalletsPeriod$, this.store.selectedWalletsUser$)
    .pipe(filter(([period, user]) => period && user))
    .subscribe(([period, user]) => console.log('period=' + period + ',user=' + user));
```

The example above should log a value as soon as both values are set.

See also: [documentation for combineLatest](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-combineLatest)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, that's exactly what I needed. I modified my [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/execute-typescript-function-according-to-a-scenario-in-angular?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstore%2Fmystore.store.ts) with the solution by adding this function directly in my store.

Answer (score 1):

You can zip your observables:

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html

This will call the subscription if both observable got a value and everytime one of them changes. But you'll need to filter your observables by "not null" or something like that because you initialize your behaviour subjects with null.

BTW: Did you tried redux or ngrx (redux for angular)? You don't need to implement your own store / action-handling / side-effect / subscription logic.

Comment: as yankee said: combineLatest could do a better job as zip.